# I can use my local apt repository as a local yum repository?

Tags: ubuntu, yum, rpm, repository, private

I'm a newbie in Linux. I have a local apt repository. I didn't want to set up a separate machine and http server for my rpm packages and occupy disk. I wonder if there is some way I can use my local apt repository as a local yum repository as well? I'm open to any suggestions. Docker etc. Because I couldn't install dependencies like yum-utils on ubuntu. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no, that's not an option. The distro that you want to use with the rpm packages will require different versions of the software and and rpm is fundamentally different than a deb package (which Ubuntu uses). Although there are ways of converting one to another, it's not possible to install an entire system that way.

If you want to use your local apt mirror, it's best to stick with the same distro.